# Move hibernate-mapping dtd to project's folder

Tags: hibernate, dtd

At this moment I have parsing exception for my Hibernate mapping file:

```
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd Nested exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    ... 43 more
```

This is because of temporary unavailability of http://www.jboss.org/
So I want to move DTD file to my local project's path.
If I just remove first part of the url (leave only hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd)I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: C:\Programs\eclipse juno\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd (File not found) Nested exception: C:\Programs\eclipse juno\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd (File not found)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
... 43 more
```

I can put it to appropriate folder, but I could get the same problem on production environment in the future. So I just want to know how can I store this file related to project's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I changed my DTD keyword from PUBLIC to SYSTEM and removed FPI. More information about it could be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration